# What is the difference between "derive" and "predict"?

Tags: terminology, definition, soft-question, models

I'm working on attaining a better understanding of physics through independent study following S&Z 12E, and my book has asked me to *derive* a quantity from given laws and principles. I was able to succeed, but it was complicated, and something I'd like to be able to understand better.

I'm wondering if this differs in usage in any meaningful way from the process of "making predictions with physics."

Is the difference simply semantic because when making a derivation you won't have necessarily proposed any physical system to realize the assumed relationships, such as $Dv^2$ as a realized fluid resistance?

The definition of "derive" that I've intuited is $$\text{A process by which physical laws and principles are taken}$$ $$\text{ with assumed quantities/relations, and traced logically}$$
$$\text{ to conclusions about the predicted relationships between quantities in the given situation.}$$

Is this correct? complete? incomplete? misleading? Is derivation simply synonym for "making predictions with physics" where the situation is taken to be partially unknown / underspecified?

I'm sorry if these tags are hit-or-miss, I'm not sure how to classify this question.

Update: Here's a mindmap detailing concepts I'm drawing from and their interrelationships.
[image: Soft Physics Mindmap]

Reference:

Young, Hugh D., et al. Sears and Zemansky's University Physics / Hugh D. Young, Roger A. Freedman ; Contributing Author, A. Lewis Ford. Pearson Addison-Wesley, 2008.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As comment by John Doty: To derive means creating a mathematical line of thought, starting with some principles, assumptions etc. to arrive at a formula or theory. (The result need not be a "prediction", it may be an explanation for a previously known result. Although the derived theoretical result will then be available to predict outcomes in similar experimental setups, where so far no results have been obtained.)

To predict literally means to make a prediction (a statement about something yet to be determined), which can be based on previous experimental evidence (the ball will fall down and not up because we have previously observed the same behavior every time we let it go), basic (qualitative) principles (the direction of the current will be ... because of Lenz's rule) or a derivation of some theoretical result (gravitational lensing, for example, derived from GR and then tested in experiment).

Comment: I understand "theory" to mean simply a principle or law that hasn't been well-tested. It occasionally seems to be used to mean system for describing a specific object.

Comment: A theory is a whole collection of principles and laws and their interrelation, it can be untested like String theory or very well tested in experiment like classical Electrodynamics or many others.

Comment: @meltyness Th usage of "theory" as "not well tested" is more common in everyday language than in physics/the philosophy of science. What you describe is called hypothesis in that context.

Comment: So maybe it's an issue that the results of derivation may always be posed as hypotheses, but are typically found to be principles in-and-of-themselves? I also fail to understand the fact that theories are explanatory, but laws and principles are predictive. Is the relationship composition -- that theories contain and relate Laws and Principles?

Comment: I think this is what I wrote, yes: Theories contain laws and principles. And all of them can be used to either explain things that you have observed or make predictions on things that you have not yet observed.